# How to modify security settings for DCOM components on Azure cloud app?

Tags: security, virtual-machines, azure, dcom

I have deployed an application to an Azure cloud service, running as webrole. I am trying to change security settings of DCOM components, but the form is disabled, although the user has admin permissions:

[image: disabled form]

Can I edit these settings and if yes how?

UPDATE:

I've traced it down to not having permissions on the Registry-Key HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/AppId/{id}. However I fail to take ownership of the key:

[image: fail]

So the question is (now): How can I take ownership of the key? Or does Azure restrict this on web role VMs?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved it by simply taking ownership over the key by selecting 'Change owner', afterwards I could change the permissions and modify the settings for DCOM accordingly.